# How does merge function works in background in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I came from Oracle background. I understood how the join(any type) work in relational data base. They use indexes, full table scans and internally they use Nested Loops/Merge sort/Hash joins to join two tables.

If it is using index, it scans the index and grab the rowid of the particular row that is matched and using that rowid it fetch the record and join with the other. There are many other things to consider to join.

- But, in case of pandas merge, what kind of methods it follows? I have referred pandas documentation and Googled for this information. I couldn't find the answer for my doubt.
- They only says how to use the merge function, but, not how it works from background.

I am assuming that each key that we specify for key_left and key_right will be set as index in each data frame and then it is using **left_df.loc[right_df.index]**. But, I am not sure.

I would request someone help me with the related documentation to go through.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.0/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py)

Comment: I'm from a similar background.  Used to looking at QEPs and changing query structure and indexes to optimise how joins and query work by adding indexes, hints etc.  I really don't think that pandas is a replacement for an enterprise database engine... it's a brilliant replacement for data analysis in Excel!  If there is heavy lifting joins and ETL - do these in the enterprise part of the stack of the end-end architecture with the tools and feature these tools offer